# Package __init__.py import all subfiles, but only load one from another script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I have created a package with the following file structure:

```
- package
  - __init__.py
  - load.py
  - train.py
  - test.py
```

My `__init__.py` file is simply an import of classes for these files:

```
from package.load import Load
from package.train import Train
from package.test import Test
```

Most of the time, I want to load all three, however on occasion I only want to load one of these classes specifically. For example in an ad hoc script (outside of the package) I want to be able to call only the Load class like so:

```
from package import Load
```

While all of the above works in this design, I have an issue where dependencies from train/test are also loaded when I import `Load` like the above. How can I setup the `__init__.py` file such that I can make the same `import` call without getting the dependency to load from train/test?

Additional explanation:

Why I am doing this: I have an issue where I want some people to be able to use the `Load` class, which only uses base python, however the Train/Test files include specialized dependencies which users of just the Load class wont want to utilize or even install.

Comment: "however the Train/Test files include specialized dependencies which users of just the Load class wont want to utilize or even install." Then `package.load` should probably be packaged seperately, no?

Comment: Generally, you are probably correct. In this case the package is a generic package which will be utilized extensively by a single team for a wide range of projects and the desire is to keep package in a single import call (mostly to take advantage of environmental variables). The issue is there is a wide range of technical knowledge of the users and some of the more complex dependencies are more hassle than it is worth trying to install them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do something very close what you want. Instead of unconditionally `import`ing all the package's classes in your `__init__.py`, you can define a function in it to explicitly import any of the ones desired (or all of them if none are specified).

`__init__.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys

print(f'In {Path(__file__).name}')

package_name = Path(__file__).parent.name
package_prefix = package_name + '.'
class_to_module_map = {'Load': 'load', 'Train': 'train', 'Test': 'test'}


def import_classes(*class_names):
    namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # Caller's globals.

    if not class_names:
        class_names = class_to_module_map.keys()  # Import them all.

    for class_name in class_names:
        module = class_to_module_map[class_name]
        temp = __import__(package_prefix+module, globals(), locals(), [class_name])
        namespace[class_name] = getattr(temp, class_name)  # Add to caller's namespace.
```

For testing purposes, here's what I put in the `load.py` script:
(I also put something similar in the other two modules in order to verify whether or not they were getting `import`ed.)

`load.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path

print(f'In {Path(__file__).name}')

class Load: pass
```

And finally here's a example of using it to only `import` the `Load` class:

`ad_hoc.py`:

```
from my_package import import_classes

#from my_package import Load
import_classes('Load')

test = Load()
print(test)
```

Along with the output produced:

```
In __init__.py
In load.py
<my_package.load.Load object at 0x001FE4A8>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a folder `oranges\`, this is our `__init__.py` file:

```py
__all__ = []

from pathlib import Path
from importlib import import_module
from sys import modules

package = modules[__name__]
initfile = Path(__file__)
for entry in initfile.parent.iterdir():
    is_file = entry.is_file()
    is_pyfile = entry.name.endswith('.py')
    is_not_initpy = (entry != initfile)
    if is_file and is_pyfile and is_not_initpy:
        module_name = entry.name.removesuffix('.py')
        module_path = __name__ + '.' + module_name
        module = import_module(module_path)
        setattr(package, module_name, module)
        __all__.append(module_name)
```

When we do `from oranges import *`, the code inside `oranges\__init__.py` cycles through the `*.py` files inside `oranges\` (except `__init__.py`), and for each `.py` file does the following:

- imports the `.py` file as a module into the variable `module` using Python's `importlib.import_module`
- sets the `module` as a variable within the `__init__.py` file (or, more correctly, within the *oranges* package) using Python's `setattr`
- finally, appends the module to the `__all__` list